# Spring Boot: WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, tomcat

I am trying to run spring boot application but i am getting an exception. I have tried many answers like `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and then running `mvn spring-boot:run`, updating spring boot 2 versions, etc but none is resolving the issue as I am getting below exception

```
2019-12-05 00:06:00.787  INFO 19840 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-12-05 00:06:00.791  WARN 19840 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack tr
ace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-12-05 00:06:00.793  WARN 19840 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-1-thread-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack tr
ace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-12-05 00:06:00.795  WARN 19840 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
 Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-12-05 00:06:00.798  WARN 19840 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory
leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.5/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
 java.base@11.0.5/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
 java.base@11.0.5/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
 java.base@11.0.5/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
 java.base@11.0.5/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823)
 org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
 org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
 org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
 org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:306)
 org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:405)
 org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:94)
 org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
 org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
 org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
 org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:119)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:706)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:692)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-12-05 00:06:00.804  WARN 19840 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web serve
r; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-12-05 00:06:00.805  INFO 19840 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'application'
2019-12-05 00:06:00.806  INFO 19840 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'security'
2019-12-05 00:06:00.807  INFO 19840 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-12-05 00:06:02.244  INFO 19840 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-12-05 00:06:02.261  INFO 19840 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-05 00:06:02.276 ERROR 19840 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean.getDescription(ServletRegistrationBean.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup(RegistrationBean.java:48) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:456) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted

[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize (TomcatWebServer.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init> (TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull (Assert.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean.getDescription (ServletRegistrationBean.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup (RegistrationBean.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup (TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal (StandardContext.java:5132)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal (StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize (TomcatWebServer.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init> (TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  37.901 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-05T00:06:03+05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project sample-project: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.
springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat: Servlet must not be null -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My main spring boot file is

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SampleProject extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleProject.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleProject.class);
    }
}
```

I am using JDK 11.0.5. I was running this on my Google App Engine with JDK 8 and it was running fine but async calls weren't working as I was getting error below.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all
>   filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java
>   code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter
>   declarations in web.xml.

Upon some research I [found](https://dev.to/saifali40/good-news-appengine-users-32i6) JDK8 on GAE doesn't support NIO so I am now working to migrate it to JDK 11.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update: My Servlet Config file**

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

After removing my Servlet config file which was probably conflicting I got below error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.<init>(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:57)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry;

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/icurious/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/icurious/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:0', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: There's a `ServletRegistrationBean` in your app with a `null` `Servlet`. Have you created one somewhere using the default constructor and then not called `setServlet(Servlet)`?

Comment: I haven't created any `ServletRegistrationBean` and previously were using the embedded tomcat.

Comment: Thanks. If you haven't created one in your own code, something else must have done so. I can't tell what that is from what you've provided thus far. Can you share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) so that we can see the full picture?

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson I have provided some more info. I am still getting exceptions. AlsoI have updated my spring boot starter parent version to 2.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: The second problem is unrelated to the first. The version of Spring Data REST inluded in Spring Boot 2.2 requires Spring Plugin 2.0 and you have Spring Plugin 1.2 on the classpath. If you need some help figuring out why that is happening, please ask a new question that includes details of your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the `ServletRegistrationBean` I found that  `springfox-swagger` version 2.9.2 wasn't compatible with JDK 11 so I removed that as well. Moreover I used (thanks for the hint [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson)) `spring-plugin-core` mentioned below it finally worked!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The failure is occurring because your application contains a `ServletRegistrationBean` with a `null` `Servlet`. This is caused by your `servletRegistrationBean`:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

When you create a `ServletRegistrationBean` you need to provide the `Servlet` that you want it to register. You can either do that by passing the `Servlet` into the constructor of `ServletRegistrationBean` or by calling the `setServlet(Servlet)` method. For example, assuming that your `Servlet` class is called `YourServlet`, you could do the following:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean =
            new ServletRegistrationBean(new YourServlet());
    registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for all of the `@Column` annotation name attributes in all of the entities. You must be using same column name for two attributes in a table/jpa entity.